# pandas groupby: selecting unique latest entries

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, unique

In the following pandas Data Frame:

```
    Name    v   date_modified
0   A   0   2023-01-01
1   A   1   2023-01-02
2   A   2   2023-01-03
3   B   0   2023-01-30
4   B   1   2023-01-02
5   B   2   2023-01-03
6   C   0   2023-01-30
7   C   1   2023-01-03
8   C   2   2023-01-03
```

How can I get two latest versions with most recent unique date_modified per group ['Name', 'v']?

In this example there are duplicates date_modified on `df.Name == C`. So far I tired to do something like this:
`df.sort_values('date_modified').groupby(['Name', 'v']).tail(2)`. This does not omit duplicates on date_modified and also for some reason return all rows not just tail of two

Comment: What is the expected output for your sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you have to drop some duplicates before:

```
>>> (df.drop_duplicates(['Name', 'date_modified'], keep='first')
       .sort_values('date_modified').groupby('Name').tail(2).sort_index())

  Name  v date_modified
1    A  1    2023-01-02
2    A  2    2023-01-03
3    B  0    2023-01-30
5    B  2    2023-01-03
6    C  0    2023-01-30
7    C  1    2023-01-03
```

Comment: Ahh, right! Thanks I have fried my brain over this. Will go to take a break.

Comment: Only that the correct version here will be `df.drop_duplicates(['Name', 'date_modified'], keep='first').sort_values('date_modified').groupby('Name').tail(2)
` (need to sort to make sure grab the latest).